# How are [version] and [versioning] different?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the difference between the tags [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version)  and [versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versioning) tags?  The two tags seem to be very similar to each other.

The [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version) tag has about 4,150 questions and the [versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versioning) tag has about 2,280 questions — those numbers include 81 questions tagged with both.

My only guess would be that [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version) might be about identifying a specific version of a program, where [versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versioning) may be about setting the version for a program.

Comment: I think both of those are useless tags.

Comment: There's no real need for any of them.

Comment: Well, one of them was created after the other one, so it should replace it, right?

Comment: IMHO version should be used when there are more than one version of the subject (e.g. PHP 4 and PHP 5) and versioning when you are talking about a versioning system (e.g. git, svn etc)

Comment: Don't we have php4 and php5 tags? They are a lot more specific and actually give us decent scope. I don't see how having a generic version flag gives us any additional information...

Comment: `version` is a noun. `versioning` is a present participle, I think. Hey - I'm a programmer, noy an English major.

Comment: versioning is the process of versioning. Version might refer to a certain version related problem of any software. I guess it's better to have a  single version tag for everything than a version tag for every single tag. That way you can search for [java][version] if you have a version related problem or want to answer question related to that. Otherwise you would have todo [java-version] and hope that the tag exists.

Answer (score 19):

[version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version) is a useless tag that could do with burnination. It could mean anything and I really don't see how it can be used in any meaningful way. The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/version/info) suggests that this tag is about version control, but that is not how the tag is used at all. It is rather used as fill-out, trash-tag material. Just take a brief look at this and you get the idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version. Quite horrible...

[versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versioning) seems to mean [version-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-control). But since [version-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-control) already exists and is a more correct term, [versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versioning) could probably do with some burnination too.

Comment: what about api versioning

Comment: @DanielA.White: What about API versioning?  If there's a need for a tag about it, it should be [tag:api-versioning] — a non-existent tag (as I type).

Comment: @DanielA.White what question would deserve such tag? "How to version my api?" The only answer would be "as you wish!".

Comment: I think this is the problem. The version tag can be used for anything, but is describing a lot. The necessity stems from the problem that low rep users can't create tags, so they use it when they have a version related problem, together with whatever software they are using. I guess it's better to have a single version tag for everything than a version tag for every single tag. That way you can search for [java][version] if you have a version related problem or want to ask/answer questions related to that. Otherwise you would have to use [java-version] and hope that the tag exists/used.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful Nah it is a nonsense tag and somebody should post a burninate request. Just read through [java + version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+version), the search results are completely incoherent.

Comment: Well, I guess the version is used with the most specific technology. So [android][version] is refering to android version most likely [java][android][version] is refering to java version in an android context. If you would want good [java][version] results for pure java then you would have to remove java from every unrelated question. Burninate will not solve the problem, but make it worse and even more inconsistent, the tag would quickly be recreated I guess, but now be non existant in old questions. Not to mention the hit in searchability and usabilty for new members.

Comment: I guess that version would have to be split into language-version buildsystem-version platform-version etc. to be disambiguous. The alternatives are 1 single version tag or millions of local single use tags.

Comment: Versioning would have to be split into versioning-code-system and versioning-release/user-system or something.

Comment: Meh, we should just stop trying to find something useful on this tag where there's no evidence of otherwise. Sometimes, even if you try to make sense of something it doesn't, because it never made sense.

Comment: Should I convert this question into a burninate request then? Or would you like to make a separate topic for that.

Comment: @Braiam I versioned my Minecraft mods once, ended up being a broken system because it didn't actually do what I tried to use it for. Then I tried to re-version with a different system and *that failed almost immediately.* I think I'm on version 3 of my api versioning system. [[tag:meta-versioning]]

Comment: @Draco18s serious question: which of the tags will put your question in front of the experts that would be to answer your minecraft question, minecraft or version?

Comment: @Braiam If I were to use my mods as an *example* of a problem I had and wanted to get some expert advice on "how to do this better" I would probably tag it....ooh...ah. [api-design] would be perfect.  I wanted to version the API in such a way that I could make the dependents rely on a specific version or higher but still make bugfix level changes to the API itself *without* increment the version number of the dependent. My v1 was just straight numerical. v2 was [release].[internal].[bugfix], but what if I had to bugfix the api? That inc'ed [release] and required a full build.

Comment: @Draco18s and here's the thing: nobody follows api-design, because, it doesn't exist as no answerer have felt the need to create a tag for that and even if it did, people would have no idea what the questions would be like. Remember, tags are for *concrete* stuff. Things that you can say *here it ends and here it starts*. There's no book about api design which covers all and every question about api design, so what we do is to shove it to another site that deals with [software architecture and design](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and say that we are creating an api.

Comment: Which moves us to the next point @Draco18s, your question would be not answered as you selected the tag that didn't put your question in front of experts.

Comment: @Braiam [api]'s tag wiki says "use [api-design]."  According to that tag, it has 259 followers and 927 questions.  That's not no-one.  That's more than [minecraft-forge] (I follow this one) *and* [computercraft] (accidentally hovered over it getting the numbers for Forge, and is apparently a "real tag" as it has a tag wiki #NotSayingMuch).  If that is considered "no one" then maybe the tag needs to be burninated and [api]'s description updated?