# Revert [version] to version 0

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

**This request is technically a duplicate of  [Remove [version]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251012/remove-version). However, that request was originally made 3 years ago, so I would like to repropose burninating [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version).**

---

[Two months ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344928/3357935), I asked if there was a difference between the tags [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version) and [versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versioning). Most users seemed to agree with [Lundin's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345004/3357935).

> [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version) is a useless tag that could do with burnination. It could mean
>   anything and I really don't see how it can be used in any meaningful
>   way.

Since my original post wasn't a proper [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request), I figured it would be a good idea make the request myself, complete with the [traditional awful title pun](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests/295586#295586). So with that said:

Should we burninate [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version)?

---

<sup>*This post originally called for [versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versioning) to be burninated as well, but was changed at the suggestion of [Tiny Giant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349156/revert-version-and-versioning-to-version-0#comment472801_349156)*</sup>

Comment: I believe that we should not create duplicated questions for burninate requests. There were already a call to action some years ago and the community opted to ignore. Why would it be different now? Should we create this same question every couple of years?

Comment: @Zanon well, we shouldn't review our policies if there are new arguments to be put forward? Remember, stuff is dynamic/fluid and can change.

Comment: [On Meta, how do you get attention for questions without an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266782/on-meta-how-do-you-get-attention-for-questions-without-an-answer) In addition to the strategies given there, posting an answer of your own in support for the burnination would also be an effective way to force a reconsideration.

Comment: @Braiam, yes, we should review our policies from time to time, but in this case, the OP didn't add new facts or arguments to burninate the tag. As Cody Gray pointed out, there are other ways to call for attention here in Meta.

Comment: If Microsoft had launched a new product called "version" that attracted tons of off-topic questions per month, creating a new post to burninate or retag "version" questions would be fine.